# Why does subtraction of two units.degC quantities give a units.delta_degC result but subtracting two units.kelvin gives a units.kelvin result in metpy

Tags: python, metpy

I'm a metpy user.

I was calculating the unit of temperature using metpy.

I found one difference in the process of subtraction.

For Celsius and Fahrenheit temperatures, subtracting or adding values will output delta_degree_celsius, but for kelvin temperature, it will be output as kelvin.

I wonder what are the differences between these and the results.

```
d1 = 10 * units.degC
d2 = 5 * units.degC

d1 - d2
= 5 delta_degree_celsius

d3 = 10 * units.kelvin
d4 = 5 * units.kelvin

d3 - d4
= 5 kelvin
```

Comment: Because Celsius is not an absolute unit. https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/tutorials/unit_tutorial.html#temperature Sure, 5 deltaDegC is e same as 5 Kelvin, but I suppose they want to remember that it came from Celsius for some reason

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to you, I understood right away.

Answer (score 0):

While Kelvin and `delta_degree_Celsius` are equivalent, the `delta_degree_Celsius` is created by Pint (the unit library used by MetPy) as part of its machinery to generically handle units that have a non-0 offset. For more information, see Pint's [documentation on temperature conversion](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/nonmult.html).